# trustManager.checkServerTrusted(...) never throws CertificateException

Tags: java, ssl

I'm working on a custom TrustManager implementation that uses an X509TrustManager and I encountered the following problem:

According to the Javadocs, a X509TrustManager is expected to throw a CertificateException:

```
void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException;
```

The CertificateException is an class that got a number of sub-classes:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException 

CertificateEncodingException
CertificateExpiredException
CertificateNotYetValidException
CertificateParsingException
CertificateRevokedException
```

Unfortunately, these exceptions are never thrown (at least not from sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl that got returned from the factory). Instead I get a sun.security.validator.ValidatoreException with different causes:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path...
```

when the CA is not in the trust-store or the cert is self-signed

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate has been revoked...
```

when the cert has been revoked

So, my question is: what is the best way to get to the real cause of certificate verification problems, especially considering the fact that we should not use from sun packages?

Cheers,
Andreas

@rxg

That's exactly my problem - I'm catching the CertificateException. However the actual type is always a ValidatorException and not one of the documented exceptions (CertificateEncodingException, CertificateExpiredException, CertificateNotYetValidException, CertificateParsingException, CertificateRevokedException). To figure out what the real cause of a validation exception was, I have to analyse the class causing the exception and to read the message, like this:

```
} catch (CertificateException e) {

if (e.getCause() instanceof java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException ) {

    if (e.getCause().getMessage().startsWith("Certificate has been revoked")) {
        // ...
    } else if (e.getCause().getMessage().startsWith("timestamp check failed")) {
        // ...
    }


} ... more ifs following ...
```

Evaluating the exception message is really bad style and definitely not reliable. Therefore my question: is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand, `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException` is a sub-class of `java.security.cert.CertificateException`, as is `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException`. When you say they are never thrown, what does your `catch` block look like?